# Run animation from particular step

Tags: android, android-layout, animation

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setStartTime(long)) `setStartTime` should help with starting animation from particular step. What I mean is if I have animation `android:duration = "2000"` I want to make it start in java from particular time e.g from 1500 or whatever else. Once again it is not delay of animation start like `setStartOffset` but start from particular step of animation.

After digging a little bit more I have found that `startAnimation` is not affected by `startTime` and always begins from the 1st frame. On the other hand `setAnimation` should be used for `setStartTime` unfortunately I can not pass there my `long` value and can not pass it into `currentAnimationTimeMillis`.

updated code

```
in MainActivity ...
Animation introani;
TextView intro;

in onCreate..
    intro= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.intro);
    introani = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.introalpha);

    ViewTreeObserver vto = intro.getViewTreeObserver(); //@diegoveloper
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            introani.setStartTime(1500);
            intro.setAnimation(introani);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                intro.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                intro.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
        }
    });
```

It still has duration of 2000 but in that case animation never starts.

Any ideas how to run animation from particular step?

Comment: what do you want to animate?

Comment: @diegoveloper I have animation `xml` assigned to `TextView`

Comment: so "intro" var is your textview?

Comment: @diegoveloper oh, I'm sorry, yes it is. Updated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLUTION

Use `valueAnimator` or `objectAnimator` [documentation lnk](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.html#setCurrentPlayTime(long)) instead of `animation`. Also to mention it was *added in API level **26!!!*** (while same string in `valueAnimator` asks for v11 [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html#setCurrentPlayTime(long)) so it could be done rather programaticaly).

Here is example

```
private static ObjectAnimator showScaleXObj(View view, long duration, long curPlayTime, float start, float stop) {
    ObjectAnimator showScaleXObj = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.SCALE_X, start, stop);
    showScaleXObj.setDuration(duration);
    showScaleXObj.setCurrentPlayTime(curPlayTime);
    showScaleXObj.start();
    return showScaleXObj;
}
```

Even though adding multiple animations would look huge it is still a nice solution.

## **OLD ANSWER** about `animation`

Apparently there is no easy way to implement this. Thanks to @diegoveleper for help unfortunately it might be impossible.

First of all that is ***tween animation***.
Here are instructions on implementation of `setAnimation` and `setStartTime`

```
    introani = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.introalpha);

    final long currAnimTime = AnimationUtils.currentAnimationTimeMillis();
    long startOffSet = 1500;
    introani.setStartTime(currAnimTime + startOffSet);
    intro.setAnimation(introani);
```

You **must** acquire *.currentAnimationTimeMillis* then use it in `setStartTime` with `long` value you want. In this case `setAnimation` works (!) and it starts animation with some delay from 1st frame.

To conclude `setAnimation` part. The `setStartTime` is literally time when animation starts

```
    final long currAnimTime = AnimationUtils.currentAnimationTimeMillis();
    long startOffSet = 1500;
    introani.setStartTime(currAnimTime + startOffSet);
    intro.setAnimation(introani);
```

and it works same as `setStartOffset` since last one is only a delay before start.

```
    long startOffSet = 1500;
    introani.setStartOffset(startOffSet);
    intro.setAnimation(introani);
```

More information. There is a way for start from particular step via `AnimationDrawable` [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804613/android-frame-animation-only-plays-first-frame) and pause/play [(just to read)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864488/how-do-i-pause-frame-animation-using-animationdrawable/7840895#7840895). Unfortunately it requires only ***frame animation*** d̶r̶a̶w̶a̶b̶l̶e̶ ̶f̶i̶l̶e̶s̶ ̶h̶e̶n̶c̶e̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶i̶̶̶s̶̶̶ ̶̶̶p̶̶̶o̶̶̶s̶̶̶s̶̶̶b̶̶̶i̶̶̶b̶̶̶l̶̶̶e̶̶̶ ̶̶̶t̶̶̶o̶̶̶ ̶̶̶p̶̶̶l̶̶̶a̶̶̶y̶̶̶ ̶̶̶g̶̶̶i̶̶̶f̶̶̶ ̶̶̶I̶ ̶g̶u̶e̶s̶s̶ ̶b̶u̶t̶ ̶i̶m̶p̶o̶s̶s̶i̶b̶l̶e̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶p̶l̶a̶y̶ ̶a̶n̶i̶m̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶.̶x̶m̶l̶.

Answer (score 0):

Call `setAnimation` after your view finish the rendering:

```
     intro= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.intro);
introani = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.introalpha);
introani.setStartTime(1500);
ViewTreeObserver vto = intro.getViewTreeObserver(); //@diegoveloper
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        intro.setAnimation(introani);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            intro.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        } else {
            intro.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }
    }
});
```

Try using `setStartOffset` instead `setStartTime` :

[setStartOffset](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setStartOffset(long))

Comment: I tried that option but as mentioned in the question that line starts animation from 1st frame. Whilst I need animation to run from 1500 frame (or duration time) out of 2000

Comment: _ @diegoveloper `OnGlobalLayoutListener` = cannot resolve and

`removeGlobalOnLayoutListener` = deprecated. Also "add after view finish the rendering" means to add your snippet after `
    introani = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.introalpha);`  ?

Comment: _ @diegoveloper "this" cannot be applied to () and OnGlobalLayoutListener = cannot resolve, and where do I put that snippet?

Comment: _ @diegoveloper `observer` = cannot resolve, and in `else` removeGlobalOnLayoutListener = deprecated.

Comment: _ @diegoveloper yes, no more errors, but still when do I pass new timer? And where do I put your snippet? I added it in onCreate after `introani = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.introalpha);` and tried introani.setStartTime(1500); in `vto` and after. Does not work.

Comment: _ @diegoveloper used it however problem with `setStartTime` and `setAnimation` are the same. `1.` animation does not start at 1500 `2.` animation does not start at all `3.` duration timer =2000 works

Comment: check your introalpha file

Comment: Try using setStartOffset instead setStartTime

Comment: _ @diegoveloper thank you! Here is what I did. `introani.setStartOffset(1500);` before vto and ` intro.startAnimation(introani);`. In that case animation starts after 1500 from 1st frame but that was working w/o vto as well.

Comment: _ @diegoveloper what exaclty should I check in _introalpha_ ? Apparently I am missing the point how `setStartTime` really works. According to documentation time passed to method should come from `currentAnimationTimeMillis()` but I can't find any way to update it.

Comment: _ @diegoveloper I am sorry I can not since goal was not to delay start but to start from some time passed.